# Flutter - How to create mini modal next to IconButton widget?

Tags: flutter, modal-dialog, popup

I want to create a mini modal opening next to the three dots icon.

[image]

Best way to create that, any suggestions?

```
IconButton(
 icon: const Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
 onPressed: () { 
   // magic here?
 }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about PopupMenuButton?
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html

```dart
PopupMenuButton<Menu>(
              // Callback that sets the selected popup menu item.
              onSelected: (Menu item) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedMenu = item.name;
                });
              },
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<Menu>>[
                    const PopupMenuItem<Menu>(
                      value: Menu.itemOne,
                      child: Text('Item 1'),
                    ),
                    const PopupMenuItem<Menu>(
                      value: Menu.itemTwo,
                      child: Text('Item 2'),
                    ),
                    const PopupMenuItem<Menu>(
                      value: Menu.itemThree,
                      child: Text('Item 3'),
                    ),
                    const PopupMenuItem<Menu>(
                      value: Menu.itemFour,
                      child: Text('Item 4'),
                    ),
                  ])
```

[image]